# gdalwarp "ERROR 1: Couldn't determine X spacing"

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, error, gdalwarp

Can someone tell what is causing this error in gdal warp "ERROR 1: Couldn't determine X spacing"?

I have a set of .xyz files in a folder that I want to convert to .tif files. The variable file_list is a list of filenames.

```
# warp coordinates of each tile
for f in file_list, desc='warp':
    bashCommand = "gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4647 -overwrite " + f + ' ' + f[:-4] + '.tif'
    process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, error = process.communicate()
```

For most of the files this command works fine, but for one it gives me the error.

Comment: If only one tif file fails you can consentrate on that. Can gdalinfo read it? Can you make a copy with `gdal_translate input.tif output.tif`?

Comment: well, I have edited my question. I have a set of .xyz files that I convert with gdalwarp to .tif files. I can not translate the file with gdal_translate neither can I use gdalinfo to show details about the file. Do you have an idea how I could check whether the file is broken or not?